# No persistence provider for entitymanager named after have imported an Maven project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I have this problem with a simple project made with maven and using spring and hibernate. This project works on eclipse on Mac. After i put it on github and after downloaded it and imported it on eclipse on Windows as exsisting maven project. But when i tried to Run on a server from eclipse it doesn't works and give me

```
org.springframework.web.util.nestedservletexception: request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.persistenceexception: no persistence provider for entitymanager named xxx
```

I already searched for a solution but I didn't find anything.

Comment: Make sure Hibernate is on the classpath.

Comment: Yes, there are the libraries. Infact annotations and classes are recognized.